# Using pipes, reading 2 numbers from parent process, child computing their sum and gives parent the result for printing

Tags: c, linux, pipe

I'm new to C and linux system programming. 
I have created 2 pipes for bi-directional communication between parent and child processes. I am reading numbers in parent for e.g:

```
1 2(enter)
```

(enter) means pressing enter to get to new line.
Using pipes, I'm sending this input to child process, who I want to compute the sum for the numbers. Then using another pipe, I'm sending the sum back to parent for printing. 
When I run the code the output doesn't show. It's like this:

```
./a.out
2 3
hamzasidiki@Hamza-PC:~/Desktop/SPMukhi/New$
```

As you can see the program is not printing the result and ending before. What's wrong in my code? Any help is appreciated. TIA.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main() {
int fd1[2];
int fd2[2];
pid_t cpid;
int wstatus;

pipe(fd1);
pipe(fd2);

cpid = fork();
if(cpid == -1) {
    perror("fork");
    exit(0);
}
if(cpid > 0) {
    //Parent
    int rc;
    char pbuff[20];
    int rcp1 = read(STDIN_FILENO, pbuff, 20);

    close(fd1[0]);
    write(fd1[1], pbuff, rcp1);
    close(fd1[1]);
    waitpid(cpid, wstatus, 0);
    close(fd2[1]);
    char pbuff1[20];
    int rcp2 = read(fd2[0], pbuff1, 20);

    pbuff1[rcp2 - 1] = '\0';
    close(fd2[0]);
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, pbuff1, rcp2);

}
if(cpid == 0) {
    //Child
    int sum = 0;
    char cbuff[20];
    close(fd1[1]);
    int rcc = read(fd1[0], cbuff, 20);

    cbuff[rcc - 1] = '\0';
    char *a = strtok(cbuff, " ");
    while(a != NULL) {
        int a = atoi(a);
        sum += a;
        a = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    close(fd1[0]);
    close(fd2[0]);
    char w[20];
    int n = sprintf(w, "Result = %d\n", sum);
    write(fd2[1], w, n);
    close(fd2[1]);



       }

           }
```

Comment: I suggest you add some debug prints (or better, use a debugger). e.g. print read return value, pbuff content, write return value, read return value, strtok return value, w (after processed by sprintf).

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me after clearing out the warnings my compiler gave me.

- Use a different variable name for the integer `a` in the while loop of your child code. It's confusing the `atoi()` function call.
- `waitpid()` expects a pointer in its second argument where you've provided an integer. Pass `&wstatus` instead or just `NULL` since you're not using the status anyway.

Comment: Thank you! I guess the error was in fact in naming char pointer 'a'!
I tried using wait(NULL) instead and still was getting no result. Changed the name to something else and it worked. Thanks ;)